# Cross-platform API for system information

Tags: memory, cross-platform, cpu-cores

I'm looking for a library that will provide this type of information:

RAM
Swap space
Number of CPUs
speed (CPU MHz)
Number of cores
Chip type

Ultimately I'll be calling into it from Java, but a C library would be fine, which I can wrap with JNI.

Platforms of interest include, but not limited to, AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Like you I was looking for a cross platform system info library and found this:

http://code.google.com/p/geekinfo/

I didn't test it yet but it might suit your needs.

good luck !

Comment: This link is now broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Sigar](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar.html) which supports the metrics and platforms that you want and has both C and Java APIs. It is GPL, which may or may not suit your needs.

Comment: SIGAR 1.6.4 is now Apache License 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to query these systems remotely?  If so, your best bet will probably be to use an [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) [library](http://www.snmp4j.org/).

Comment: We already have a process running on the box. Plan was to have that process perform discovery, and pipe the results back to an existing client application.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the following documentation site: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_abstraction_layer

Also check out the Open Audit computer auditing and inventory tracking system http://www.open-audit.org source code and their script for auditing linux machines for examples of querying a hal database.

You may also want to check out the [Nagios Plugins](http://nagiosplugins.org) project for a large stash of open source scripts for collecting stats remotely from other machines.  [Nagios](http://nagios.org/) is designed as an Enterprise administration / up-time monitoring system for data centers, but the scripts could easily be used standalone for monitoring in different configurations.