# Multiplatform library for accessing system resource information

Tags: c++, resources, multiplatform

I need a multiplatform library to determine how much RAM the OS has free, how much of it is installed, how high the CPU usage is and so on. The library should work in both Windows and POSIX environments. Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I know it's OS-specific by definition; I can write some small library to abstract this on my own, but I'd rather not do this, if there is already some library available.

Comment: I don't think this is available in portable form - this is really OS-specific.

Comment: If you really want something like this, preprocessor directives are probably the way to go.  Something like #if (condition that only holds on a Windows) (nextline) /*Code for windows*/ (nextline) #elseif (condition that only holds on POSIX) (nextline) /*Code for POSIX*/ (nextline) #else (nextline) #error Wrong operating System.  Or #ifdef.

Comment: @Whovian, read my edit. I know *how* to do it, if I have to do it on my own; I just ask whether anyone know any such *ready to use* library.

Comment: What is your definition of "free ram"? is it the ram not used by applications? or does that include the ram left after subtracting all the amount of OS caches? Will it include committed but not already populated pages?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I mean the physical RAM that OS can allocate to new process. I know that OSes utilize "unused" RAM, but I want it to tell me how much of it is left for applications to use. I don't want to get too much into details of implementation of given OS, just to get an *approximation* of "free" (I think it's still the best word here) RAM in the system.

Comment: The answer about [geekinfo](http://code.google.com/p/geekinfo/) from [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654643/cross-platform-api-for-system-information) might help you

Comment: Isn't it covered by : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process ?

Comment: You probably won't find a generic POSIX way to do this, it will be very OS specific, like Linux, BSD, etc.  Even different versions of Linux may require a different handling.

Comment: @JoelFalcou, thanks for linking that question, it will definitely become handy if I'll have to implement this by myself.

Comment: @tinman, geekinfo looks interesting, although it's not quite what I need.

Comment: @SteveTownsend: If you can write multi platform libraries in general, why shouldn't it be possible that such library covers generic runtime information? It is the job of a library to hide platform specifics ...

Comment: @phresnel - of course it's possible to do this, for example by using macros to switch to platform-specific APIs as suggested above. The point is that there is no single API set that you can call on multiple platforms to get this info, so you are going to have to manage the platform-specific code somehow. My original response said that there was no such library I know of.  If that's incorrect - great.

Comment: @SteveTownsend: Looks like I've misread 'available' with 'possible', beg your pardon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is almost the same question here, and it has an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/871614/344347