# Multi platform memory usage in c++

Tags: c++, windows, linux, macos, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

what is the best way (multi platform) to get the memory usage in c++?
It's possible to get also a CPU usage?

Comment: Please clarify: You want to get the overall memory footprint of your own process or other processes? Is this a runtime requirement or you need it for debugging?

Comment: Possible duplictae: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517295/multiplatform-library-for-accessing-system-resource-information

Comment: I would like to know the employment runtime of my program written in C++ without using system tools. I would put these calls in some parts of my code